# Midnight Commander Editor status line decryption

Tags: linux, midnight-commander

What is `mcedit` status line symbol decryption?

[image]

There are 4 status symbol places there:

1. `B` -- Block text selection
2. `M` -- Modified
3. (I don't know)
4. `O` -- I don't know

I also don't understand what is `1+` in the status string `L:[  1+ 0 ...`

I have not found the explanation anywhere. Could anybody explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I've (partly) found the answer myself, finally. It's [here](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/91a428db5cc5a063bde923c94bf9f7a0a80675ab/src/editor/editdraw.c#L170).

```
    g_snprintf (s, w,
                "[%c%c%c%c] %2ld L:[%3ld+%2ld %3ld/%3ld] *(%-4ld/%4ldb) %s  %s",
                edit->mark1 != edit->mark2 ? (edit->column_highlight ? 'C' : 'B') : '-',
                edit->modified ? 'M' : '-',
                macro_index < 0 ? '-' : 'R',
                edit->overwrite == 0 ? '-' : 'O',
                edit->curs_col + edit->over_col,
                edit->start_line + 1,
                edit->curs_row,
                edit->buffer.curs_line + 1,
                edit->buffer.lines + 1, (long) edit->buffer.curs1, (long) edit->buffer.size,
                byte_str,
#ifdef HAVE_CHARSET
                mc_global.source_codepage >= 0 ? get_codepage_id (mc_global.source_codepage) :
#endif
                "");
```

So, the 4th symbol `O` is the `overwrite` edit mode. It's toggled by pressing the `Ins` key. And the 3rd symbol is `R` -- `macro_index` (macro recording?). And the `1+` is `start_line + 1` (what is `start_line` then? I guess, it has something to do with bookmarks).